# How to prevent a user in Firestore from creating and reading more than one document without using Firebase authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database that I only use to check if the user has passed the app's trial period. It has one collection called "*users*" and each document in it has its Document ID value set to the `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` of the user it belongs to and it has one field inside it that's the timeStamp of when the user installed the app.

Currently the security rules are like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, create: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not using Firebase authentication because I don't want the user to have to login to Firebase in order to use the app.

Is there a way to set the security rules so that each user can only create and read one single document (his own)? I don't want a hacker to create millions of documents or to read other documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't rely on client side security.  Firebase Authentication has a type called Anonymous.  This will allow your user to start using the app in a way that you can control with security rules.  If/ when they are ready to sign up, you can convert a user to a conventional sign-in provider.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

The user ID assigned to the user of an Android app with Anonymous Authentication, persists until the app is uninstalled (I believe).

You can then add security rules to ensure that a user is only able to read/write to a single document in a collection or only read/write documents which they have created.

### Write one document per user

```
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

### Only read/write documents created by the user

```
    match /mydocs/{mydocId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.authorId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.authorId;
    }
```

## Rules are not filters

With these rules, you will not be able to simply fetch all documents from the collection and only view those which match the user.

### Get the user document

```
db.collection("users").document(userId).get()
```

### Get documents authored by the user

```
db.collection("mydocs")
  .whereEqualTo("authorId", userId)
  .get()
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I take it this anonymous authentication doesn't require the user to login or even to know that Firebase is being contacted? In that case can I just use it indefinitely instead of conventional sign-in?

Comment: Also what security rules can be used with anonymous authentication to prevent the user from reading and creating more than one document?

Comment: I've updated my answer with example rules and code.

Comment: The user will be logged in without having to perform any login process.

Comment: How do these security rules prevent someone from creating an unlimited amount of documents? Shouldn't there be a condition next to `create` that checks if the user already has a document?

Comment: The example with the `users` collection uses the `uid` as the document ID, so the user can only create one.  The `mydocs` example shows a scenario where a user may want to create multiple documents. I just edited my answer to correct an error in the single user document example

Comment: But how can I use `uid` as the document ID when a user's `uid` can randomly change due to the anonymous authentication? How will the user be able to read the document belonging to them if they no longer have the `uid` it was created with?

Comment: The user ID assigned to the user of an Android app with Anonymous Authentication, persists until the app is uninstalled.  If this isn't sufficient, you could use a unique ID from the device, but this will fail if the user changes their phone.

Comment: Is it possible to use the the unique ID from the user's device as the document ID (so that  the user can always access their own document even after re-installing the app) but at the same time use anonymous `uid` to prevent the user from creating or reading more than one document? For example can I add an `int` counter to the security rules that counts how many times the user with a certain `uid` has created a new document?

Comment: Yes, you can use any ID that you want to, as long as it complies with Firestore's limits and you can include a `userId` field. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields
The best way to manage a document counter is to trigger a Cloud Function each time a new document is created and increment a value in the user's main document.  You can check this value in your Security Rules before allowing a new `create`

Comment: Hey sorry for piling up the questions but what is "Firebase installation ID (FID)"? Is it like the `uid` of anonymous authentication?

Comment: It is the ID of an app installation on a device.  It's not something that I'm familiar with.  It does create temporary auth tokens.  Maybe you can find further details online or ask a separate question on SO.  Good luck with your app